# Way to Get 3 types of input of similar kind in Perl

Tags: perl, input

I am a novice in Perl, so I would like some help. I am writing a program, where the user can give me up to 3 different types of input and I need to extract specific data.

The user can give me any one of the three:
ASP_72_2
D72_2
72_2
(ASP = residue name, D = residue code for ASP, 72 = residue number, 2 = transmembrane number)

Is there a clever way to store the data in one line?

My idea (pseudo code) would be to check substring of each input like the following.

```
if ((substr($input, 0,3)) eq 'ASP')
{
        do way 1;
}elsif ((substr($input,0,1)) eq 'D'))
{
        do way2;
}
```

etc...etc...
Ultimately, I want to be able to process different residue names, different residue codes, residue numbers, and TM numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use separate regular expressions, but using captures to extract the numbers at the same time:

```
if ($input =~ /^ASP_(\d+)_(\d+)$/) {
    &do_way1($1, $2);
} elsif ($input =~ /^D(\d+)_(\d+)$/) {
    &do_way2($1, $2);
} elsif ($input =~ /^(\d+)_(\d+)$/) {
    &do_way3($1, $2);
} else {
    print "Input not recognized: $input\n";
}
```

Then write your various do_wayx() like this:

```
sub do_way1 {
    my ($residue_number, $transmembrane_number) = @_;
    # ... do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a valid way although i'd do it with regular Expressions:

```
    if ($input =~ /^ASP/){
        do_way1($input);
    }
    elsif ($input =~ /^D/){
        do_way2($input);
    }
    elsif ($input =~ /^\d{2}/){
        do_way3($input);
    }
    else {
        not_recognized($input);
    }

sub do_way1 {
    my $input = shift;
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use one regular expression

```
use strict;

my @input = qw(ASP_72_2 D72_2 72_2 AST_33 BD_33);

foreach (@input){

   if(my ($type, $value) = /^(ASP_|72_|D)(.*)/){
      print "type = $type, value = $value\n";
   }else{
      print "couldn't match $_\n";
   }
}
```